# Youtube live url not working in media3 Exo Player - Android Java

Tags: java, android, youtube-data-api

We have a requirement to show live streaming in android app for specific users only.
Currently normal videos are playing fine but stream / live URL is not working.
Tried each video format in MIME Type but gives source error.
androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors could read streams.

```
exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext())
              .setMediaSourceFactory(new DefaultMediaSourceFactory(new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()).setLiveTargetOffsetMs(5000))
              .setHandleAudioBecomingNoisy(true)
              .setWakeMode(WAKE_MODE_LOCAL)
              .setTrackSelector(new DefaultTrackSelector(this))
              .setBandwidthMeter(new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(this).build())
              .setLivePlaybackSpeedControl(new DefaultLivePlaybackSpeedControl.Builder().setFallbackMaxPlaybackSpeed(1.04f).build())
              .build();
```

```
MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
              .setUri(mediaUri)
              .setMimeType(MimeTypes.VIDEO_MP4)
              .setLiveConfiguration(new MediaItem.LiveConfiguration.Builder().setMaxPlaybackSpeed(1.02f).build())
              .build();
```

Is there something missing?

Expecting to smoothly run live streaming youtube url's.